# Output distribution to a maximal number of columns

Tags: shell, columns

I have a bash script `foo` that provides me with many short lines of output. Think `ls -1`. To get a more compact presentation, I would like to distribute the output over multiple columns, like `ls -C`.

I know that constructions like

```
foo | paste - - - | column -t -s $'\t'
```

will give me a fixed number of columns, in this case three. How can I **dynamically** adjust the number of columns to output width and terminal width such that I always use the maximal number of columns?

Comment: Does your terminal set the `COLUMNS` variable? would something as simple as `foo | column -c $COLUMNS` work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is actually almost too simple:

```
foo | column
```

without any arguments to `column` does the trick. I think I have never actively used `column` without `-t` before. Thanks to steeldriver for the suggestion to leave out this argument.

Comment: @don_crissti `columns` seems to automatically use the current value of `$COLUMNS` for all terminals I tried (putty, screen, xterm). At least it works without additional arguments no matter how I resize.

Comment: Fwiw, it doesn't work for me (xterm, final term, gnome terminal) unless I  `export COLUMNS` before running it... and it only works with `column` not with `columns`...

Comment: I fixed the typo.

Comment: If I don't export `COLUMNS`, neither version works for me if I use them in (non-interactive) scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: `echo $(foo) | fold` where you can specify `-w WIDTH` to use something other than 80 columns.